# Editing the value of position in a different class

Tags: java

I've got a class called `Jar` with fields called `position` and `Stone` `stone`.

I've also got another class called `Chest` with fields called `position`, `jar1`, `jar2` and `jar3`.

Basically I need the variables `jar1`, `jar2` and `jar3` to have a set `position` of `4`, but when I create a new instance of `Jar`(`Jar()`), the `position` is set to `0` and so I was wondering how I would approach changing the value of the position. Thanks.

```
public class Jar
{
    private int position;
    private Stone stone;




    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Jar
     */
    public Jar()
    {
        position = 0;
        stone = null;
    }

    public Jar(int initPos, Stone stone)
    {
        position = initPos;
        this.stone = stone;
    }

     public void move(int distance)
    {
       position = position + distance;
    }

    public void moveTo(Jar jar)
    {
        jar.stone = stone;
        stone = null;
    }

}

public class Chest
{
    private int combination;
    private int position;
    private Jar jar1;
    private Jar jar2;
    private Jar jar3;


    public Chest()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter chest combination (5-10): ");
        combination = Global.keyboard.nextInt();


        position = 4;
        jar1 = new Jar();
        jar2 = new Jar();
        jar3 = new Jar();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could call the argumented constructor public Jar(int initPos, Stone stone)

Comment: Call your parameterized constructor like `jar1 = new Jar(position, stone)` and so on.

Comment: when I do this, it says the variable stone could not be found

Comment: Pass `null` like `jar1 = new Jar(position, null)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Call the constructor that receives two arguments like this: `jar1 = new Jar(4, null);`, providing `4` for the `position` value and `null` for the `stone` value.

**Option 2:**

Create an overloaded constructor to receive just the position as argument:

```
public Jar(int initPos) {
    position = initPos;
}
```

And call it in the `Chest` constructor like this: `jar1 = new Jar(4);` (the same with the other instances).

**Option 3:**

Create the `jar`s and then call its `move(int distance)` method:

```
jar1 = new Jar();
jar1.move(4);
```